# Foursquare API Checkin users of a venue

Tags: foursquare

I am trying to get the users info for the people who checked in for a venue

Is there any API endpoint to get the atleast the basic info of the users who checked in for a venue

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In a [venue detail](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) request, if your users have auth'd through Foursquare, you can see their friends that have been there. Your app can see users currently at a venue if 1) one of your auth'd users just checked in there, or 2) your users are a manager of that venue.

These should give you some "mini" or compact [user responses](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/user) and to get more data, you can make a [user detail request](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/users)